# input type checkbox with for attribute

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I can't understand why I can't see anything for the second input element. in the first one i use the for attribute and in the second one i tried to place the input element inside the label as discribe here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

can someone tell me what is the problem??

http://jsfiddle.net/v4Dde/102/

```
<input type='checkbox'  id="borderCheckBox"/>
<label for="borderCheckBox"></label>

<label class="labelClass">
<input type='checkbox' class="checkboxClass"/>
</label>

input[type=checkbox] {
   display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
   background: black;
   height: 16px;
   width: 16px;
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: red;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

.checkboxClass + .labelClass {
   background: black;
   height: 16px;
   width: 16px;
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 0 0 0 0px;
   //border-right: 1px solid blue; 
}

.checkboxClass:checked + .labelClass {
    background: red;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do? And where you are getting an error?

Comment: I'm trying to set 2 different background colors for input type checkbox (red and black). when I run this example i can see only the first checkbox but the second is invisible. I cant understand why i cant see the second input element.

Comment: If you get result with 1st method then why you go for 2nd?

Comment: I want to understand what is the problem. The second solution seems to be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

It's your

```
input[type=checkbox] {
   display:none;
}
```

try change from `none` to anything else like `block` or `inline` depending on what type you want.

Comment: But it doesn't change the input component background color to red or black for the second input component .